# Combine 2 elements in a list into a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I am trying to combine two elements in a list to form a nested list in the original list. I am stuck. I can iterate through the list and get the specific elements, but I'm not sure how to create a nested list with them in the original list.

This is the original list.

```
[
  {'LIN02': 'GS', 'LIN04': 'MF', 'LIN03': 'BOSEF2', 'LIN06': 'ST', 'LIN05': 'BOSTIK', 'LIN07': 'BOSEF2', 'id': 'LIN'}, 
  {'PID02': 'TRN', 'PID01': 'F', 'PID05': 'EFA+ 28 OZ TUBE ADHESIVE', 'id': 'PID'}, 
  {'PID02': 'MAC', 'PID01': 'F', 'PID05': 'INSADH', 'id': 'PID'},
  {'MEA04': 'EA', 'MEA03': '1.000', 'MEA02': 'SU', 'id': 'MEA'}
]
```

I would like it to output like this.

```
[
  {'LIN02': 'GS', 'LIN04': 'MF', 'LIN03': 'BOSEF2', 'LIN06': 'ST', 'LIN05': 'BOSTIK', 'LIN07': 'BOSEF2', 'id': 'LIN'}, 
  [
    {'PID02': 'TRN', 'PID01': 'F', 'PID05': 'EFA+ 28 OZ TUBE ADHESIVE', 'id': 'PID'}, 
    {'PID02': 'MAC', 'PID01': 'F', 'PID05': 'INSADH', 'id': 'PID'}
  ],
  {'MEA04': 'EA', 'MEA03': '1.000', 'MEA02': 'SU', 'id': 'MEA'}
]
```

This is what I have so far.

```
loop_2000 = ['LIN02': 'GS', 'LIN04': 'MF', 'LIN03': 'BOSEF2', 'LIN06': 'ST', 'LIN05': 'BOSTIK', 'LIN07': 'BOSEF2', 'id': 'LIN'}, {'PID02': 'TRN', 'PID01': 'F', 'PID05': 'EFA+ 28 OZ TUBE ADHESIVE', 'id': 'PID'}, {'PID02': 'MAC', 'PID01': 'F', 'PID05': 'INSADH', 'id': 'PID'}, {'MEA04': 'EA', 'MEA03': '1.000', 'MEA02': 'SU', 'id': 'MEA'}]
for n in enumerate(loop_2000):
for line in enumerate(n[1]):
    if line[1]["id"] == "PID":
        print(line)
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to solve this, but I found a work around.

```
pid_list = []
pid_index = []
for line in enumerate(loop_2000):
    if line[1]["id"] == "PID":
        pid_index.append(line[0])
        pid_list.append(line[1])
loop_2000.insert(line[0], pid_list)
del loop_2000[pid_index[0]: pid_index[0] + 2]
```

Comment: The output combines these two elements in the list as a nested list...   {'PID02': 'TRN', 'PID01': 'F', 'PID05': 'EFA+ 28 OZ TUBE ADHESIVE', 'id': 'PID'}, {'PID02': 'MAC', 'PID01': 'F', 'PID05': 'INSADH', 'id': 'PID'}.  A more readable example would be, original = [1,2,3,4,5,6] newlist = [1,2,[3,4],5,6]

Comment: I just wonder why you would want to do something like that. Your structure is no more consistent. What would make sense is to have all of the LIN together, all of the PID together and finally of the MEA together in respective nested lists.

Comment: I eventually am using json.dump(loop_2000, filename, indent=4) to convert the list to a json file, but I need the PID elements to be two separate json objects in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
list2 = []
list2 = [element for element in list1 if element['id'] !='PID']
list2.append([element for element in list1 if element['id'] =='PID'])
```